# UIButton added to view is not responding to touches

Tags: delegates, uibutton, xamarin.ios

I have a UIButton that is added to a UIImageView (it's a big chart)

The button appears nicely and I have the TouchUpInside attached to a delegate:

```
this.TouchUpInside += delegate { ShowPopOver (); }
```

This event is never fired though. The button has `UserInteractionEnabled=true`

I add the button to the top of the view:

```
UIButton b = new DataPointButton (frame);
_parentView.AddSubview (b);
_parentView.BringSubviewToFront(b);
```

Is there anything I need to do to enable touches on code created buttons?

Comment: UIButton subviews that have been added a UIImageView don't work at all. Enable userinteraction on the uiimageview

This is probably because interaction is turned off by default on image views, but I've not checked this.

Comment: So you resolved it by enabling user interaction on the UIImageView? Please post it as an answer so the question does not show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UIView` the `UserIntaractionEnabled` property is set to `YES` by default when there is a button on it. Howewer, in case of `UIImageView` it is `NO` by default.
Set it to `YES` to make buttons work:

```
myUIImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```